# Why does my code raise an AttributeError instead of a ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I written parts of the following class:

```
class something(dict):

    @staticmethod
    def _is_hashable(obj):
        if type(obj) == str:
            return True
        if not hasattr(obj, "__hash__") or getattr(obj, "__hash__") == None:
            return False
        if hasattr(obj, "__iter__"):
            if len(obj) == 0:
                return False
            for x in obj:
                if not x._is_hashable():
                    return False
        return True


    def __init__(self, initial=[], **kargs):
        for k, v in kargs.items():
            if self._is_hashable(k) and self._is_hashable(v):
                pass
            else:
                raise ValueError
        super().__init__(initial, **kargs)
        self._rdict = {}
```

However, when I test with

```
b1 = something(a = ((),(),((),[])))
```

and

```
b1 = something(a = (1,2,{1:'a'}))
```

it raises an AttributeError instead of a ValueError

When I do this

```
b1 = something(a = {1})
```

This does raise a ValueError.
Can someone tell me why and how I can change my code so all of the above examples raise a ValueError?

Comment: Provide the traceback; it usually helps pinpoint your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call `x._is_hashable()` where `x` is an element of your inputs. That's not going to work, because that's not a method on arbitrary objects.

I'm guessing the intent was something like:

```
if not something._is_hashable(x):
```

so you recursively call the `_is_hashable` utility of the `something` class.

Mind you, this is all kinda nonsense anyway. The correct way to test if something is hashable is to just use it in a context where it must be hashed, or to precheck, do:

```
try:
    hash(obj)
except TypeError:
    # Not hashable
else:
    # It's hashable
```

Comment: Your advice helped. I've fixed my problem. Thanks!